# Jquery Programatically Click button with no unique id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Here is the HTML of the button i would like to click:

```
<div style="" class="widgetPlaceholder widgetExpireTurbo" data-widget="turboBinary_tradologic_expireTurbo">

<input type="button" value="15s" class="expireTurboRuleInterval activeRule" data-ruleid="149">
<input type="button" value="30s" class="expireTurboRuleInterval" data-ruleid="148">
<input type="button" value="45s" class="expireTurboRuleInterval" data-ruleid="147">
<input type="button" value="1m" class="expireTurboRuleInterval" data-ruleid="106">
<input type="button" value="2m" class="expireTurboRuleInterval" data-ruleid="107">
<input type="button" value="5m" class="expireTurboRuleInterval" data-ruleid="108">

</div>
```

I wish to click the button with the `value="30s"` progmatically via jquery.

Here is the URL: https://binarykings.co.uk/traderoom-aspx?game=turbo&view=single&lang=en&filter=currencies

Thanks

Comment: With regards to your "*Thanks but it doesnt seem to work on my target site*" comments, please create a live demo from your minimal code at a site such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
jQuery('input[value="30s"]').click();
```

Comment: Note that without a tag-name (`input`, `button`, `option` etc) you're implying the universal selector (`*`); which means that jQuery (or in this case the underlying CSS parsing of the browser) is looking at *every* element in the document (which slows down the selector a little, relative to a selector specifying the element-type).

Comment: Thanks for your input but it doesnt seem to work on my target site: https://binarykings.co.uk/traderoom-aspx?game=turbo&view=single&lang=en&filter=currencies

Comment: @DavidThomas Yeah, i suppose didn't think about that i'll edit my answer.

Comment: @user1838222 It works fine for me when i type it in the console.

Comment: @Anton that looks like my answer now :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/jZU8H/2/)**

```
$(':button[value="30s"]').click();
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt seem to work on my target site: https://binarykings.co.uk/traderoom-aspx?game=turbo&view=single&lang=en&filter=currencies

Comment: I could not see the code in page source, you need to define click event as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[value="30s"]').click();
```

Comment: Hi, this doesnt seem to work when i test it :S

here is the url: https://binarykings.co.uk/traderoom-aspx?game=turbo&view=single&lang=en&filter=currencies

Comment: what file is the jquery in? i cant find it

Comment: it looks like you will need to pop the code in to run after your ajax loaded content

Answer (score 0):

You need to use selector on attibute and also call click when page is loaded:

```
$(function(){$('input[value="30s"]').click();})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzZK6/)